# How do I solve this vector equation for Lambda?

Tags: vectors

I want to project a point m onto a plane that is spanned by three points (a triangle, basically). In my task, these were the instructions I got:

```
projection: m on plane abc
        1. plane normal: n = normalize((b-a) x (c-a))
        2. plane P: p n - a n = 0
        3. ray R: m + λ n
        4. insert R in P: (m + λ n) n - a n = 0, solve for λ
        5. projected point x = m + λ n
```

What already confused me was if step 2 and 3 were actually necessary. It looks like I can directly go from step 1 to 4 and just plug in the numbers, then solve for Lambda.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to switch around the equation to solve for Lambda, since you cannot divide by vectors. This was my naive approach but of course it can't work:

```
        (m+λ*n)*n - a*n = 0         | +a*n
              (m+λ*n)*n = a*n       | /n
                  m+λ*n = a         | -m
                    λ*n = a - m     | /n
                      λ = (a - m)/n
```

Obviously, step 2 is already wrong. But I've got no idea how to get that Lambda extracted otherwise.

Some help?

Answer (score 1):

It's going from here 
   (m+λ*n)*n = a*n       | /n

to here
       m+λ*n = a         | -m

that you've made your blunder. I'm assuming that "*" here denotes dot product, because that's really the only thing that makes sense. So really, you've got 
$$
(m + \lambda n) \cdot n = a \cdot n
$$
Use bilinearity of dot-product to get
\begin{align}
m\cdot n + \lambda (n\cdot n) &= a \cdot n\\
\lambda (n\cdot n) &= a \cdot n - m \cdot n\\
\lambda (n\cdot n) &= (a-m) \cdot n\\
\lambda &= \frac{(a-m) \cdot n }{ (n\cdot n)}\\
\end{align}

and that's your formula for $\lambda$.

Comment: But in the last step you are dividing again.

Comment: Risking that I will now sound like a moron: I don't know what a dot product is. The task just described "p n" with a space and had me left guessing what to make of it.

Comment: Ignorance is different from stupidity. It's fine to ask about something if you've never heard of it -- that's how we learn! If you're going to be doing vector arithmetic, you should probably read up on the basics. The dot-product of vectors $(a, b, c)$ and $(x, y, z)$ is $ax+ by + cz$, i.e., multiply term-by-term, and then sum up.  The wikipedia page might be a good place to start.

Comment: $n\cdot n=1$ (see step 1).

Comment: Good point. Given OP's claim of ignorance of the dot product, I wasn't certain that "normalize" was meaningful. But it does save 3 multiplies, two adds, and a divide. On the other hand, normalizing takes those same operation AND a square root, so unless you need $n$ normalized for other reasons, it's not clear that it's a good idea to do this.